# How to fetch public content from Instagram without creating developer account for each account?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

We are having a 200+ properties and they have Instagram Account. Now we are trying build page which display Public Content of particular Property.

like, we will have a URL something like this : https://xxxx.com/index.php?r=socialmedia/view&name=CapitolYardsDC

So then we will display Public Content of Instagram for that Property in above URL. But for that we will need developer account,

But we have a 200+ properties, so creating developer account for each property is not feasible. Is there a way around?

Comment: you just need one dev account and use that for all

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Instagram provides public access in few cases.
My App was fit in **"My product helps brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights."** case. 
So i have submitted a permission review with video and my app got approved.